# How can i get the last inserted record in Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I have created an activity in which i have a `textView`. In this `textView` i append some records from a `mysql` database. I want to set a different color, to the last inserted record, not to the last record from the `JSONArray`. How can i achieve that?
This is my code:

```
JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("statistics");
for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject student = users.getJSONObject(i);

    String userName = student.getString("username");
    String score = student.getString("score");

    statistics.append(userName + " " + score + " \n");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you insert something into a DB, you will get the _id as return value. `final long id = db.insert(Receipt.TABLE_NAME, null, receipt.getContent());` So essentially, it should be your server which tells you about it.

Comment: "I want to set a different color to the last inserted record", the last inserted record isnt the last record from the json array?

Comment: @Skynet: And in my case, how can i set a different color to single record?
@helldawg13: No, isn't the last record from the json array. I say that, because when i want display the record using `getJSONObject(users.length()-1)` it displays the last record from the json array not the last inserted record from the database. If it helps, in this [way](http://gogo.ro/31.txt) i add the records.

Comment: Its easy, as a clap:  `if(isLastInsert) {yourtextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);}`

Comment: Ok, but the `isLastInsert` is the same with the `id` from the first comment?

Comment: No buddy, isLastInsert should be sent as a flag in your JSOn from the server.

Comment: I need this `isLastInsert`. So, how can i send it the as a flag in my JSON from the server?

Comment: I have in my php file on the web server, something like this: `$lastInsertId = $connect->insert_id;` How can i use this variable in my activity?

Comment: Could you post the JSON you are getting from the server? You just have to add one more field, indicating that its the last insert.

Comment: I figure it out. The $lastInsertId was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the last record from database and before appending that record to textview, do following to change color of text.

```
Spannable word = new SpannableString("record to be inserted"); 
word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

statistics.append(word);
```

Comment: Ok, but in which way can i do that? Can you please show me how?